# Evento ao pressionar tecla 2 vezes

Tags: c#

Eu tenho o seguinte evento:

```
    private void TelaAcao_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue.Equals(27))
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

O resultado disso é que toda vez que pressiono `ESC`, o formulário é fechado. Porém, eu gostaria de que ao pressionar uma vez, seja chamado um método para limpar os controles e se pressionado com **TODOS** os controles vazios, ele fechasse a tela.

Como posso fazer isso? Um `if()` dentro deste primeiro `if (e.KeyValue.Equals(27))`? Tenho que passar de campo em campo verificando se eles são igual a "`String.Empty`"?

Comment: Geralmente o `ESC` é utilizado para fechar a tela, inclusive tem uma propriedade no formulário para habilitar isso, sem precisa codificar qualquer tecla, se não acha melhor utilizar uma associação de teclas?

Comment: Fiquei interessado sobre essa propriedade, mas a ideia é que uma vez que o formulário estivesse preenchido, o primeiro `ESC`limpasse a tela, ao invés de fechar direto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um método pra checar controle vazio:

```
bool CheckVazio(Form formulario)
{
     foreach (Control item in formulario.Controls){
          if (item is TextBox && !((TextBox)item).Text.Equals(string.Empty))
               return false
          else if (item is ComboBox && ((ComboBox)item).SelectedIndex > -1)
               return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

Método para limpar Controles:

```
void LimparControles(Form formulario)
{
     foreach (Control item in formulario.Controls){
          if (item is TextBox)
              ((TextBox)item).Text = string.Empty;

          else if (item is ComboBox)
              ((ComboBox)item).SelectedIndex = -1;
     }
}
```

No seu evento KeyDown adicione:

```
private void TelaAcao_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyValue.Equals(27))
     {
          if (!CheckVazio((Form)sender))
              LimparControles((Form)sender);
          else
              this.Close();
     }
}
```

OBS.: Como não sei quais controles vc usa, usei um `TextBox` e um `ComboBox` como exemplo,  mais pode usar outros controles adicionando-o ao método que limpa e que check seguindo a mesma lógica.

Espero ter ajudado!